Writing a PDE in a moving coordinate
I am trying to understand the following PDE by writing it in a reference frame marked by the red cross.
$\partial_t h(x,t)+ \partial_x (u(x,t) h(x,t))=0,$
where h shows the height. I want to write an equation for the dynamics of h from a reference frame moving with the tip (red cross). Since $u$ is not constant, I cannot use the method used in the transport equation. Could anyone guide me on how to find the dynamics of h in the marked reference frame (assuming that the cross moves with a constant velocity v)?
image dynamics

@whpowell96 can you explain more? I am looking for a solution h, I don't know what it is

My mistake, I meant that the position of the cross in your picture solves the characteristic equation. Is that point where $h=0$?

Yes, that is where h=0. Could you please write an answer if you know how to write the eq?

Define new coordinates $(\xi,\tau)=(x-vt,t)$, then use the chain rule to rewrite the PDE as $\partial_{\tau}h-v\partial_{\xi}h+\partial_{\xi}(uh)=0.$

Thanks. Is $v$ the velocity of the cross?  If h does not change in the reference frame on the red cross, does it mean that in your formula $\partial_{\tau} h=0$?@Gonçalo

Yes, $v$ is the velocity of the cross. If $u$ is constant and $v=u$, the PDE in the moving reference frame reduces to $\partial_{\tau}h=0$, which means that $h$ has a fixed shape there.
